У меня сломался pycharm, помогите
Недавно переустанавливал windows, и когда я решил запустить одну из кодов он мне пишет
error: please select a valid python interpreter, Поискав в инете что делать я вышел на эту настройку: 
Вопрос, что мне надо вписать в Location чтоб он заработал?

В Location должен быть путь для создания новой среды (обычно папка venv в папке с проектом)

Если проект уже есть в виртуальном окружении, то выбрать Existing,

в Location указать путь до виртуального окружения
C:\Проекты\мойПроект\venv

в Base interpreter C:\Проекты\мойПроект\venv\Scripts\python.exe


